# Split dictionary by keys in Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I would like to clarify this code, especially variables. I am a newbie in `python`.

**GOAL:**
I would like split data dictionary `pairs` by `keys` of this dictionary. The output is list of lists of class `Ward`. I think, my solution is too complicated, is another better solution?

```
class Ward:
    def __init__(self, code, data):
        self.code = code
        self.data = data


def prepare_data_for_templates(cs, h, f):       
    pairs = {'201': ['<tr><td>Dunajsk&#225; Streda</td><td>201</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Dunajsk&#253; Kl&#225;tov</td><td>201</td></tr>\n'], '205': ['<tr><td>Ko&#353;oln&#225;</td><td>205</td></tr>\n',]}

    print "Pairs: " + str(sorted(pairs.keys())) + "\n"

    #output data - ba, tt...
    OUT = []

    BA = []
    TT = []

    for k, v in sorted(pairs.iteritems()):
        #print k + "\n", v
        if int(k) < 199:
            BA.append( Ward(k, v )
        elif int(k) < 299:
            TT.append( Ward(k, v )

    OUT.append(BA)
    OUT.append(TT)


    for j in OUT:
        for i in j:
            print i.code

    return OUT
```

**EDIT**: Thanks for the answer, I updated my code using JSON.

tab01.json:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "101", "c01": "mun1"
        },
        {
            "id": "101", "c01": "mun2"
        },
        {
            "id": "205", "c01": "mun3"
        },
        {
            "id": "205", "c01": "mun4"
        },
        {
            "id": "205", "c01": "mun5"
        }
    ]
}
```

code.py:

```
import os, json

def prepare_data_for_templates(file):       

    pairs = {}
    codes = []

    with open(file, "r") as input:
        json_obj = json.load(input)

    for d in json_obj["data"]:
        codes.append((str(d["id"]), d))

    for c in codes:
        pairs.setdefault(str(c[0]), []).append(c[1])

    for k, v in pairs.iteritems():
        with open( str(k) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(v, outfile)

prepare_data_for_templates("tab01.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

"Clean up this (working) code" is generally not a good SO question because it's very vague.
I've downvoted, but, in this particular case, you have a few things that can be done right off the bat.

---

### Use New Style Classes, or Tuples

Your `Ward` class appears to be unnecessary.
Unless there is other functionality there that you are not showing, you should just create tuples.
Instead of `Ward(k, v)` just use the tuple `(k, v)`.

If you do need the class, at least write it as a new style class, `class Ward(object):`
The syntax that you have used, `class Ward:` is deprecated and supported only for historical reasons.

### Keep Data External from Code

Right now, you have a giant, messy, hard to work with variable,

```
pairs = {'201': ['<tr><td>Dunajsk&#225; Streda</td><td>201</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Dunajsk&#253; Kl&#225;tov</td><td>201</td></tr>\n'], '205': ['<tr><td>Ko&#353;oln&#225;</td><td>205</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Leopoldov</td><td>205</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Trnava</td><td>205</td></tr>\n'], '705': ['<tr><td>Pu&#353;ovce</td><td>705</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Radatice</td><td>705</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Rokycany</td><td>705</td></tr>\n'], '304': ['<tr><td>Rudnianska Lehota</td><td>304</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Sebedra&#382;ie</td><td>304</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Se&#269;</td><td>304</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>&#352;&#250;tovce</td><td>304</td></tr>\n'], '305': ['<tr><td>Selec</td><td>305</td></tr>\n'], '103': ['<tr><td>Modra</td><td>103</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Pezinok</td><td>103</td></tr>\n'], '101': ['<tr><td>Bratislava - Nov&#233; Mesto</td><td>101</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Bratislava - Podunajsk&#233; Biskupice</td><td>101</td></tr>\n'], '806': ['<tr><td>Plechotice</td><td>806</td></tr>\n', '<tr><td>Trebi&#353;ov</td><td>806</td></tr>\n']}
```

This is pretty much impossible to sustain if you want to add data, or the data changes.
This looks like partially parsed HTML of some kind, so that might be a better form in which you store your data, and let your python code parse the HTML every time it runs.

If you want to keep processed data, and not the original HTML source, I'd recommend putting this into a JSON file; something like this:

```
{
  "201": {
    "name": "Dunajsky",
    "municipalities": [
      "Streda",
      "Klatov"
    ]
  },
  "205": {
    "name": "Kosoln",
    "municipalities": {
      "Leopoldov",
      "Trnava"
    }
  }
}
```

Your data is pretty dirty, so this is just my best guess at the structure that you are trying to represent.
This will make your life much easier moving forward.

You can then parse this data using the python [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library:

### Don't Make a List of Lists

As far as I can tell, you are trying to sort data.
There is no need for a list of lists for this purpose -- it's unnecessarily complicated, and, as a result, confusing.

Consider something more like this:

```
with open('wards.json', 'r') as f:
    json_obj = json.load(f)

# assume the structure above is used for the JSON
# don't do any validation (because that would require more work with something
# like a JSON schema, and I'm too lazy for that)

# convert the object to a list of tuples, and convert codes from strings to ints
code_list = []
for (code, data) in json_obj.items():
    code_list.append((int(code), data))

# sorting tuples does a dictionary-order sorting, so this will sort on keys,
# then on the data components of the tuples (which presumably don't have
# meaningful ordering)
return sorted(code_list)
```

A slightly cleaner version of the conversion into `code_list` would use a comprehension:

```
code_list = [(int(code), data) for (code, data) in json_obj.items()]
```